# C# IPv4/IPv6 agnostic socket listener

Tags: c#, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to to figure out how to create a protocol agnostic socket listener in C# - it should grab IPv4 and IPv6 requests. Everything I can find on Google seems to be C. Attempting something similar to what I saw for C, I tried the following code:

```
/*Socket*/ m_sock = null;
/*IPAddress*/ m_addr = null;
/*int*/ m_port = port; /*port passed to function*/
/*int*/ m_listenqueue = listen_queue_size; /*also passed to function, number of pending requests to allow before busy*/
IPAddress[] addrs = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList;
if(family == null) m_addr = addrs[0];
else
{
    foreach(IPAddress ia in addrs)
    {
        if(ia.AddressFamily == family) /*desired address family also passed as an argument*/
        {
            m_addr = ia;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(m_addr == null) throw new Exception(this.GetType().ToString() + ".@CONSTRUCTOR@: Listener Initailization Error, couldn't get a host entry for 'localhost' with an address family of " + family.ToString());

m_sock = new Socket(m_addr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
/*START "AGNOSTICATION LOGIC"... Tried here...*/
if(m_addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6) //allow IP4 compatibility
{
    m_sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.AcceptConnection, true);
    /*fails*/ m_sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AcceptConnection, true);
    /*fails*/ m_sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.AcceptConnection, true);
}
/*END "AGNOSTICATION LOGIC" */
IPEndPoint _endpoint = new IPEndPoint(m_addr, m_port);
m_sock.Bind(_endpoint);
/*... tried here*/
m_sock.Listen(m_listenqueue);
/*... and tried here*/
```

I've tried the logic at the three places marked, and regardless of where I put it, the two listed lines will throw an invalid argument exception.

Can anyone recommend to me how I should make a socket that will listen to both IPv4/IPv6?

Comment: What about fixing the `InvalidArgumentException`?

Comment: `Bind` and `Listen` methods should be enough, no need for `SetSocketOption` at all.

Comment: [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/11/18/494769.aspx) might be of help?

Comment: @Anton Kovalenko - That's what I thought, but this produces a 'Connection Refused' error when others try to connect from IPv4 (if the listener was created using InterNetworkV6) or IPv6 (if the listener was created using InterNetwork).

Comment: Derived from Sami's comment - `m_addr = IPAddress.IPv6Any` and `m_sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);` are both needed for the address and socket options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sock.SetSockOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPV6Only, 0); to set the socket to allow connections with other protocols than IPv6. It will work from Vista onwards.

[SocketOptionName documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx)

Comment: Worked, though I needed to set the address used to bind the socket `IPAddress.IPv6Any`